# Why are in_app_purchase events not getting fired from iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, in-app-purchase, app-store, firebase-analytics

We have a Firebase project and two project apps (iOS and Android) set up for a Unity mobile game. This game handles its in-app purchases through the Apple App Store and Google Play store which we'd like to track using Firebase's automatically-collected [in_app_purchase](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?hl=en#:%7E:text=form_name%2C%20form_destination%2C%20form_submit_text-,in_app_purchase,-(app)) events. However, Firebase Analytics shows we're only getting these events from Android devices despite the fact that iOS players are also making successful purchases. Other automatically collected events like `screen_view` and `ad_reward` are correctly showing up for both platforms, so this just seems to be an issue with `in_app_purchase`.

The docs entry on `in_app_purchase` mentions it'll be ignored on iOS if the purchase is invalid or flagged as sandboxed, but if either were the case with our IAPs then none of our iOS users would be able to receive their purchases as they currently are. I also confirmed that the App Store ID for the iOS Firebase project app is correct, just in case it might've been looking for IAPs from a non-existent app. Lastly, I noticed an `IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED` flag in our app's GoogleService-Info.plist that is set to false. That looked a bit suspicious, but given most of the other automatically-collected events are coming through fine (and it doesn't even appear to be used in the Firebase GitHub repo), I suppose it isn't related to `in_app_purchase` specifically.